# How to find `L` in these intersecting right and scalene triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm realizing a bit rusty on my trigonometry and geometry. I'm trying to solve for `L` in the following setup:

[image: geometry1]

where I have a right triangle that has height `H`, hypotenuse `M`, and top angle of $\theta$. I then have a scalene triangle that is intersecting this with a partial length `d` and side length `m`. I want to solve for `L` as a function of $\theta$ in the end but am having some trouble getting there. The variables that I do know are `H`, `M`, `d`, and $\theta$. To start, I made the scalene triangle into two right triangles like this:

[image: geometry2]

Making this new triangle will have top angle $\theta$ also since it is similar to the big right triangle I believe. So I now have heights `h`, and hypotenuse `m`. I know the value of `m` is in this case also. This is where I'm stuck and not sure what to do next. In the following diagram, I have labeled a few more things:

[image: geometry3]

I can solve for `a`. If I can solve for `b` then just add it to `d` and easily solve for `L`, but I'm not sure how to find `b`.

Again, in the above diagram, the known variables are `M`, `m`, `H`, `d`, and $\theta$ and I can easily calculate `h` and `a`.

Comment: If $H$ is the entire height of that right triangle, then you have no way of finding $L$, since the rightmost angle, where $d$ and $L$ meet, can be whatever it wants, and it doesn't change the measurements we're given (in the top figure).

Comment: $b = (M- n) \sin \theta$.

Comment: Oops, I fixed my top figure. I know `m` from the gecko also. I forgot to include that in the top figure.

Comment: @Mick how did you find that?

Comment: But isn't $a+b=\sqrt{M^2-H^2}$?

Comment: M - n is the hypotenuse and b is equal to the opposite side of the $\theta$ in the top triangle.

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly straightforward to solve analytically. Place the vertices of the right triangle at $A(0,0)$, $B(0,H)$ and $C(-M\sin\theta,0)$. The right-hand end of the segment that you’re trying to measure is at $D(d,0)$. From your last diagram, we can easily find that $h=m\cos\theta$, $b=m\sin\theta$, and so the other end of the line segment is at $E((m-M)\sin\theta,m\cos\theta)$. From here, it’s just a matter of applying the Pythagorean theorem: $$L^2=\|E-D\|^2=m^2\cos^2\theta+(d+(M-m)\sin\theta)^2$$ which you can simplify and rearrange as needed.